# In Python, what is the reason for 'overwriting' a default argument of 0?

Tags: python

I'm reading the source code of a Scrapy-Redis example project, https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis/blob/master/example-project/process_items.py, which contains the following:

```
def process_items(r, keys, timeout, limit=0, log_every=1000, wait=.1):
    limit = limit or float('inf')
```

It seems to me that the *de facto* default for `limit` is `float('inf')`, because if it is not specified it initially assumes the default value `0`, and is then immediately converted to `float('inf')` in the line containing the Boolean operator `or`.

My question is: why not just set the default `limit=float('inf')` in the `def` line? Is there a reason for this pattern?

Comment: it has a purpose when default argument is a `list` or another mutable object but here it seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is driven by a command line interface. The command-line interface uses `0` as a default for `limit`. This is a de-facto standard of disabling limits in cases like these, because using other options (having the command-line user use `float('inf')` instead, or a separate switch that disables the limit again if set by other means) is needlessly complicated.

The function then uses the same default; presumably to make it easier to use that function *outside* the command-line use case (by importing the script), making it reasonably self-documenting. That the actual code uses `float('inf')` instead is then an implementation detail.

There is no *technical* reason to use `default=0` over `default=float('inf')` however.

Comment: There is one slight difference: overwriting `default=0` with `float('inf')` prevents the user from calling the function with value `0` whereas `default=float('inf')` still allows calling the function with `0`.

Comment: @Wombatz: It doesn't *prevent* users from calling the function with `limit=0`. The behaviour just doesn't change between using `limit=0`, `limit=float('inf')` or leaving out `limit` altogether.

Comment: Yeah i formulated that quite badly. Your wording is much more precise